# How do I get a this.state.value from other components in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native

I got it to work calling getValue in classtwo from classone but is there another way of doing this? Is there a easier way to get this.state.value from classtwo?

I tried putting static getValue as static but it always throw me an error. Anyone can help?

Thanks!

```
class ClassOne extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            classtwo: new ClassTwo(),
        };
    }

    CallGetValue(){
        this.state.classtwo.getValue();
    }
}

class ClassTwo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: 100,
        };

    }

    getValue(){
        return this.state.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*Declaring a new*"? What is wrong about it?

Comment: "*I tried putting static getValue as static*" - why would you do that?

Comment: I only need 1 instance for the whole application lifespan. Like I have only a searchbar for the app and I keep declaring new SearchBar() for classthree classfour.

Comment: Why do multiple of your classes contain an instance of `SearchBar`? Who instantiates that single `SearchBar` that you want to use in your application? Maybe it should rather be parameter of your constructor functions? And btw, `new` is not a declaration, it's a construction.

Comment: That looks like the way to do it. Why do you think there would be another way?

Answer (score 4):

It should look like this.

```
    class ClassOne extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                classtwo: 0,
            };
        }
            componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                if (nextProps.classtwo && (this.state.classtwo != nextProps.classtwo))
                    {this.setState({classtwo: nextProps.classtwo});}
            }
    }

    class ClassTwo extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
                    this.changeValue = this. changeValue.bind(this);
            this.state = {
                value: 100,
            };

        }

        changeValue(value){
            this.props.changeValue(this.state.value);
                    this.setState(value: value);
        }
    }

    class ClassZero extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.changeValue = this. changeValue.bind(this);
                this.state = {
                        classTwoValue: 0,
                };

        }

        changeValue(value){
                this.setState(classTwoValue: value);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <ClassOne classtwo={this.state.classTwoValue}/>
                    <ClassTwo changeValue={this.changeValue}/>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks janaka but i dont get this part can you explain a little on this: `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`

Comment: this fires when a component receives a prop and just before render is ran. see react-native life cycle.. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html