# React modify state with extern component

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner with react and i got a problem,
I want to update state to a component by one another component .
There is my html :

```
    <div id="leftmenu"></div>
    <div id="systeme"></div>
```

I actually hide component in my LeftMenu component with :

```
var LeftMenu = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
 return {modif: false};
 },

render: function() {
return(
  <div className="col s2">
    <ul id="slide-out" className="side-nav fixed">

      <li><a className={this.state.modif ? 'validate' : ' validate hidden'}><i className="material-icons right">done</i>CONFIRMER ET REBOOT</a></li>
      <li><a className={this.state.modif ? 'cancel' : 'cancel hidden'}><i className="material-icons right">stop</i>TOUT ANNULER</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
)
}
});
```

I want modify modif state when my Systeme component fire an action,
It is possible ?

Thank's ;)

Comment: Same question yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826277/how-do-i-get-a-this-state-value-from-other-components-in-react-native/32830541#32830541

Comment: You can use PubSub, Flex or another event system to communicate between your components.

Comment: I would argue against flux/pubsub/redux in this case. Just make a third component that has both of these components as children and communicate via callbacks. If you start realizing you'll need to do this often, it may be time to introduce dependency.